Problem solving 6 piece plastic puzzle
I bought this toy in a sphere, which contained a plastic cross puzzle. At first it was solid, but after moving one piece that is bit rounded (like a hinge) it was easily disassembled. But I can't get it back in one piece. Picture of said pieces:


Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!

Your pieces, color-coded for reference:

The assembled puzzle, showing relative positions of the pieces:

 

The order in which the pieces are assemble is often important, though I cannot say precisely what that order is for this puzzle. If needed, I can show the orientation of each piece in the assembly, though that may be easy to determine for anyone with the pieces in hand.

You are awesome, it helped a lot.

As OP noted that they rotated a piece like a hinge, I would guess that the purple piece which is rounded in the original picture needs to be rotated by 180°, then you can move out the light blue piece to the top. The reverse operation is the last step in the assembly.
